# Is there a way to recreate span in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying a paragraph with Javascript, without the use of HTML. I am only adding it to a HTML id. I want to make some of the words in the text cursive without changing the font of the whole paragraph. Is there a way to recreate the HTML  element in Javascript and positioning onto the text?

I know there's:

```
document.createElement ("span")
```

but I don't understand how and if it can it be inserted into:

```
 document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = "A quote and one word has to be cursive";
```

How to have the word "cursive" displayed in cursive, while "A quote and one word has to be" not.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “Span on Javascript” is really not a _good_ question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make one word in the string cursive by putting the strong tags around it like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "A quote and one word has to be <strong>cursive</strong>";
```

Comment: Not really, I already am doing that. I want to change the style of the quote I am displaying with Javascript.